# Logarithmic legend for raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, legend

I would like to have a logarithmic scale legend for my raster, anyone know how to do this in QGIS?

Comment: Do you mean in a map composer legend?

Comment: Best I can do is manually set break points to log-scale values (eg 0.01,0.1,1,10,100) in a pseudocolour palette - but that is piecewise linear between logarithmic points.

Comment: You may have to log-transform your raster, colour it linearly, and then change the labels on the legend. I don't see a way to automate this, so get your calculator out.